# SPOJ KFSTB - Help the Commander in Chief: Wrong Answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

The problem statement asks to find the number of paths from a given source node to a destination node in a directed acyclic graph.

I'm trying to implement this using dfs with dp for optimization. I've tried several small test cases for which the code seems to work fine. I think the problem is with large test cases but I do not know how to test on them. As the number of paths can be very large we're to use modulo. My code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#define MOD 1000000007
using namespace std;

typedef vector<long long int> vi;
typedef vector<vi> vii;

vii graph;
vi memo;

long long int dfs(int u, int t)
    {
        if(u==t)
            return 1;
        if((memo[u]%MOD)>0)
            return memo[u]%MOD;

        for(int i=0;i<(int)graph[u].size();i++)
        {
            long long int count = (dfs(graph[u][i], t))%MOD;
            memo[graph[u][i]] = (memo[graph[u][i]]%MOD + count%MOD)%MOD;
            cur_count = (cur_count%MOD + count%MOD)%MOD;
        }
        return cur_count%MOD;
    }

int main()
{
    int d, c, b , s, t, i, a1, a2;
    cin>>d;

    while(d--)
    {
        cin>>c>>b>>s>>t;

        graph.assign(c+1,vi());

        for(i=1;i<=b;i++)
        {
            cin>>a1>>a2;
            graph[a1].push_back(a2);
        }

        memo.assign(c+1, 0);
        memo[s] = dfs(s, t)%MOD;

        cout<<memo[s]<<endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

In the function dfs:
The array ***memo[]*** for an element "i" is used for memoization to remember number of paths possible to the destination from the "i"th node.
**count** variable gets the number of paths for current node being visited i.e. "i" and **cur_count** gets the total paths from all the nodes directly connected to the node "u"

It would be really helpful if I could get some tips or pointers.

Link to the original problem is here: http://www.spoj.com/problems/KFSTB/

Comment: I am not familiar with SPOJ, but having competed in the ACM programming contests, I remember that you must be very careful about the actual input.  If the problem says the values will appear on a *single line*, then you should make sure that your program always reads a single line and then parses the input from it.  There would be traps built into the test data to check that you adhered to the specification.

Comment: Should I use scanf instead then or read input as a string?

Comment: [OT]: You may reduce scope of variable (remove global, use loop variable in loop, ...). `total` seems unused.

Comment: @Siddharth from my point of view, it is simply 100% DP but not dfs...(PS: got ACed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are asking for some "tips", here's some:

1. Keywords: DAG
2. No self-loop / multiple edge cases
3. Not really about the I/O format this time (Space, line feed, etc)
4. Re-Initialize for every test case!! (esp. for STL stuff like vector<>)
5. Long Long
6. **Think backward: from destination to starting point**

Ask for more if you still get stuck :)

Comment: Thanks. I already kept these points in mind but by tips I meant some advice regarding my code, i.e. if it's buggy somewhere ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. ACed :)